# Visual Studio 2017 creates empty output folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Given a VS solution content (**Solution.sln**) content:

```
...
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SomeModule1", "SomeModule1\SomeModule1.csproj", "{SomeModule1 GUID}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SomeModule2", "SomeModule2\SomeModule2.csproj", "{SomeModule2 GUIDB}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SomeModuleX", "SomeModuleX\SomeModuleX.csproj", "{SomeModuleX GUID}"
EndProject
...
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug_X|Any CPU = Debug_X|Any CPU
        Debug_2|Any CPU = Debug_2|Any CPU
        Debug_1|Any CPU = Debug_1|Any CPU
        ...
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {SomeModule2 GUID}.Debug_X|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug_X|Any CPU
        {SomeModule2 GUID}.Debug_X|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug_X|Any CPU
        {SomeModuleX GUID}.Debug_X|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug_X|Any CPU
        {SomeModuleX GUID}.Debug_X|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug_X|Any CPU
        ...
        {SomeModule1 GUID}.Debug_2|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug_2|Any CPU
        {SomeModule1 GUID}.Debug_2|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug_2|Any CPU
        {SomeModuleX GUID}.Debug_2|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug_2|Any CPU
        {SomeModuleX GUID}.Debug_2|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug_2|Any CPU
        ...
        {SomeModule1 GUID}.Debug_1|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug_1|Any CPU
        {SomeModule1 GUID}.Debug_1|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug_1|Any CPU
        {SomeModule2 GUID}.Debug_1|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug_1|Any CPU
        {SomeModule2 GUID}.Debug_1|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug_1|Any CPU
...
```

And a **Standard.props** file found in solution (this is imported in every VS project via `<Import Project="..\Standard.props" />`) :

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug_1|AnyCPU'">
    ...
    <OutputPath>D:\ProjectPath1\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug_2|AnyCPU'">
    ...
    <OutputPath>D:\ProjectPath2\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug_X|AnyCPU'">
    ...
    <OutputPath>D:\ProjectPathX\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
 ...
</Project>
```

For the sake of the example, let's say that i work on *SomeModule1.csproj* with the configuration *Debug_1* that builds the assembly on path `D:\ProjectPath1\` with a structure like this:

```
├── ProjectPath1\
│   ├── SomeModule1\...
│   ├── SomeModule2\...
│   ├── SomeModuleX\ (empty folder, is not selected for building in 'Debug_1')
```

---

**Current situation:**

Me and my team work on **Solution.sln** that consists in 35 projects (see upper partial example) that has multiple solution configurations (see upper partial example). Each configuration has his own output path where the VS build the files into.

**The problem:**

Every time i change the active configuration **without building it** VS recreates all the paths from its `output` path with empty folders for the current configuration. Also, it creates an empty folder for `SomeModuleX` that is not included in `Debug_1` solution configuration

Example: If i change from *Debug_1* to any other, let's say *Debug_2* and some empty folders appears on my drive:

```
├── ProjectPath1\
│   ├── SomeModule1\... (my folders)
│   ├── SomeModule2\... (my folders)
│   ├── SomeModuleX\ (empty folder, is not selected for building in 'Debug_1')
├── ProjectPath2\
│   ├── SomeModule1\ (empty folders)
│   ├── SomeModule2\ (empty folders)
│   ├── SomeModuleX\ (empty folders)
```

If i change to *Debug_X* some other empty folders appears on my drive:

```
├── ProjectPath1\
│   ├── SomeModule1\... (my folders)
│   ├── SomeModule2\... (my folders)
│   ├── SomeModuleX\ (empty folder, is not selected for building in 'Debug_1')
├── ProjectPath2\
│   ├── SomeModule1\ (empty folders)
│   ├── SomeModule2\ (empty folders)
│   ├── SomeModuleX\ (empty folders)
├── ProjectPathX\
│   ├── SomeModule2\ (empty folders)
│   ├── SomeModule2\ (empty folders)
│   ├── SomeModuleX\ (empty folders)
```

If i delete `ProjectPath2` and `ProjectPath3` folders and change between solution configurations, the folders appears again...

---

**What can i do?**

So, what can i do to avoid this? Is there any settings in VS that i can modify? I tried `IntermediateOutputPath` with no luck. I will mention that, in our situation, we can't use the `Working Directory` from `Debug` settings?

I admit this isn't a show-stopper, but it drives me crazy sometimes the fact that i have a bunch of empty folders (equals with the number of configurations) on my drive (yeah, i know, OCD).

---

**Long story, short:**

How do i tell Visual Studio: "Do not create empty folder of the `<OutputPath>Path</OutputPath>` unless i press *Build* or *Rebuild* command!"?

---

LE: Issue submitted to MS here ([link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/481571/visual-studio-2017-creates-empty-output-folders-1.html)) for anyone interested about this subject

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the problem. You say that when you change the configuration, VS clear the output directories?

Comment: @Baruch, i hope now is more clear.

Comment: related: [How do I prevent Visual Studio from creating obj folders in my source directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1415443/33499)

Comment: @wimh, i don't mind the obj folders, my problem is that i don't know how to tell VS not to create output folders such as bin\Debug if i don't use that configuration.

Comment: The related question just shows that visual studio contains bugs in similar situations. So maybe this is a bug too.

Comment: @wimh, yeah, i see. I was hoping that this was a different problem, i did some research and i could not find anything to help me.

Comment: @wimh, i submitted and error report to MS. Hopefully someone from there will take a look on it.